# WebKit2.JavascriptResult.get_value() throws exception "TypeError: Couldn't find foreign struct converter for 'JavaScriptCore.Value'".

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, pygobject, javascriptcore

I am writing a python3 + webkit2 + gtk3 based GUI. Everything works fine, but when I tried to use WebKit2.WebView.run_javascript_finish() in a callback function, getting the return (a WebKit2.JavascriptResult objetc), e extrat the value with WebKit2.JavascriptResult.get_value(), I received a "TypeError: Couldn't find foreign struct converter for 'JavaScriptCore.Value'".

I have a "from gi.repository import JavaScriptCore" on the imports, and I dont know why this error is occuring.

ps: Sorry about my terrible english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, using the JavaScriptCore library isn't supported in Python.

The definitions in `gi.repository.JavaScriptCore` only include opaque definitions for `JavaScriptCore.Value` and `JavaScriptCore.GlobalContext` in order to provide type information for functions that use those types; as you can verify by looking in `/usr/share/gir-1.0/JavaScriptCore-4.0.gir`. But as you've discovered, you can't actually call those functions because there's no information on how to convert those types to native Python objects.

I recommend writing a function in C which takes in your `WebKit2.JavaScriptResult` and fetches whatever information you need from it, and then exporting that function in its own private GIR library. So you would not use any JavaScriptCore types in your Python code. This is what it might look like:

```
from gi.repository import MyAppPrivate
# ...
def on_javascript_finish(obj, res):
    result = obj.run_javascript_finish(res)
    my_real_results = MyAppPrivate.process(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, C and GIR are a bit more complex than I can deal with, but I am happy about get a answer.